# Relationship between objects

Tags: php

I got the models `Post` and `Category`. A `Post` is assigned to a `Category`. A `Category` has many `Post`s. They should be stored in a database. I implemented the following classes for it:

`Models/Post.php`:

```
class Post {
    /**
     * Title of the post.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $title;

    /**
     * The category that is assigned to the post.
     *
     * @var Category
     */
    public $category;

    public function __construct($title, Category $category) {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->category = $category;
    }
}
```

`Models/Category.php`:

```
class Category {
    /**
     * Name of the category.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * Posts that are assigned to this category.
     *
     * @var Post[]
     */
    public $posts;

    public function __construct($name, array $posts) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->posts = $posts;
    }
}
```

When I want to display a post, I will fetch it via an ID from a database. But what about the category? When I want to get the name of the category (to display it in the meta informations below the post) I have to fetch all posts that belongs to this category.

So my questions is: Is it better to store the IDs of the posts in `Category::$posts` instead the entire objects?

Comment: Cyclical relationships like this are generally a code smell (hint: it smells like sweaty socks). Either sever that relationship entirely, or provide a different way to retrieve posts belonging to a category outside of that class.

Comment: @Snowman: To resolve the cycle I have to remove `Category::$posts`. Would it be a good idea to write a class `Mapper\Category` that has a method like `getPostsOf($id)` where `$id` is the ID of the category in the database? In this method I would run through the posts and fetch that ones that `category_id` matches the `$id`.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question correctly I cannot see the problem. With posts and categories are stored separately in the database the relationship between them should be stored inside a junction table. Then when you fetch a post by its ID you can lookup the corresponding category inside the junction table. An example:

Categories table columns:

- id
- name
- description

Posts table columns:

- id
- title
- contents

Junction table columns

- category_id
- post_id

Both columns inside the junction table are foreign keys of their respective table columns. So lets say you fetch post with an ID of `123`. You then lookup the database row in the junction table where the column `post_id` equals `123`. You now have the specific category ID and can now fetch only its specific details.

I hope this can help you, happy coding!

Comment: Yes, I also would do it like this, but e.g. I only want the name of the category. So I have to instantiate a `Category` object and because that object holds posts I also have to instantiate many `Post` objects.

Comment: Ah okay. Then I would create a new class called something like `MetaCategory`. This should only store minimum information. You could then extend your current category from this to avoid code duplication. Or you could just pass en empty array of posts.

Comment: Will a Post have more than one Category assigned to it?

Comment: With a junction table you can have a `1:many` and `many:many` relationship. The deciding factor is whether the same post ID appears with  different category IDs.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, you have designed your models in such a way that you can't have a category without posts.

You have multiple ways of solving this, I will cover a couple.

**1. Utilize Inheritance and have 2 category objects.**

Have 2 category classes. `BaseCategory` and `CategoryWithPosts` inheriting from `BaseCategory`. Unless you need all posts in your category object, instantiate BaseCategory. In the constructor for CategoryWithPosts load your posts.

**2. Have the posts lazy loaded.**

Supply an instance of PostService to your category class upon instantiation and expose a method named `GetPost()`. This way you can operate on your category class as you need and when you need the posts, just call the method.

I am pretty certain you don't need posts in most of the instances of your category class.